# Excel, Determine where data takes a dive

Tags: excel, performance, graph, statistics, standard-deviation

- I'm trying to determine where, in a set of measurement data, the data takes a dive...
- ... so I can plot a vertical line and
- ... plot a horizontal line in the graph.

I have no problem doing the 2nd and 3rd bullet points above on my own, so that's taken care of.

The problem I need help with is the first bullet point - determining WHERE the data takes a dive - WHERE the data crosses a threshold that basically says, "Whatever-it-is you're measuring, is no longer performing as it is expected to.".

**Here's what I'm doing:**

I am taking measurements using a measuring device and that device is logging the measurements in its internal memory and allowing me to download that measurement data to my computer into a csv when the test session is complete.

I pull that csv into an xls and plot the data on a graph. (see attached image)

**Here's what I want to do:**

If you look at the attached image I would like to find the value where the data DEFINITELY crosses BELOW the horizontal line so I can say, "Here is where the device being tested 'gave up the ghost' and was no longer able to perform as desired."

**What the data roughly looks like:**

Each measurement set will have the rough look and feel of the attached image but slightly different each time. (because each object I am testing will have roughly the same performance characteristics but they all have their own manufacturing defects and variations.)

The data set for the attached image is a data set of 7000 measurements.
I never really know where the horizontal line will be.

Examples of the data sets I have gotten in the past several tests look like this:

(394 to 0)

(390000 to 0)

(3.88 to 0)

(375000 to 0)

(39.55 to 0)

(59200 to 0)

and each data set will have about 1,000 to 7,000 measurements each.

**Here's how I was trying to solve this issue:**

I was using SLOPE() and trying to latch onto where the slop of the line took a dive / started to work its way to a zero slope (which is a vertical line) so when it starts approaching a really small slope then it MUST be taking a dive.  That didn't really work.

I was looking at using STDEV.P() in Excel and feeding it the entire data set.  Then I was looking at doing the same thing but feeding it only the first 10, 30, 60 measurements but then I thought - we never really know just how many measurements will come through.  Then I thought I would use the first 10% of the measurements and feed that to STDEV.P().

Please let me know what you think of this and please let me know of any ideas you may have.

Thanks.

H

[image]
[image: Some sample measurement data sets. (These are just snippets of the data sets that I have been receiving. Some are really small which were for testing purposes and others are really large data sets. This is just to give you an idea of the data I'm graphing and trying to deal with as described above.)]

[image: Data jumps around so it's hard to measure the slope of the previous few data points with the next or current data point measurements.]

[image: Negative, 1 and Positive slope before dive. This throws a monkey wrench in things.]

[image: Added image to show that data measurements actually go UP from time to time and that would cause problems with the =SLOPE() solution suggested - Big thanks to Ken for the SLOPE() solution! Haven't got it working yet - ran into this fun issue of data going the wrong way - the measurements...you-would-think should only go down (based on the project i'm working on) but for some odd reason they do go up from time to time.]

Comment: if you hover over the blue line around where the dive happens, you can see the values of each plot point, and from there you can determine the point where it first goes below the threshold.

Comment: Scott - thanks for the comment!
Your statement is correct and I agree with it. I need a way for the xls to determine where the data is taking a dive.  The client needs this to be automatically done for them based on the data that the xls received.

Comment: If the data is a decay, you can identify the drop off by comparing the slope for the most recent two data points, with the previous two data points.  =SLOPE(B2:B3,A2:A3)>SLOPE(B3:B4,A3:A4) flags "true" when it drops off in some sample data i had.

Comment: Hi Ken.  Thanks for the response.  The data jumps around A LOT.  So comparing the previous few data points with the current few presents some challenges. (see additional attached image with a magnified view of the part where the data starts to dive)  I will take a look using your suggestion.

Comment: BTW ... correction to your statement regarding slope.  Slope = rise / run.  A vertical line doesn't have zero slope; it has infinite slope.  Zero slope is a horizontal line.

Comment: Whoops. Thanks.  I did have a bad feeling inside while writing about what a horizontal slope's value was and what a vertical slope's value was.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work to flag when the decay rate increases.

[image]

Comment: Hi Ken.  I will try this and see how it works.  Thanks.  H

Comment: Hi Ken - I'm editing my original post to add an additional image that refers to your post above and shows a snag in this regarding some measurements going UP (which they shouldn't but they do).

Answer (score 0):

To find what 'direction' your data is going in you need the derivative.
Excel doesn't have a derivative formula but you can set it up pretty easily by using the (change in y)/(change in x) as demonstrated here:
http://faculty.educ.ubc.ca/sanderson/lab/CLFbiom/demo/diff.htm

I would then check a formula which counts how many datarows you have (=COUNTA(A:A) or similar) 
Then uses that to get a step of 10% of your data 
Then check the value of the derivative in a cell against a cell 10% further down. If it's still a negative (to account for the slight downhill at first) then you'll know

Comment: Thanks, JJWL for the response!   

I will try this in addition to Ken's info above. (I haven't solved my problem yet so I'm going to try all suggestions.  :-)   )

Answer (score 0):

The right way to go about this is to model the data with an unknown discontinuity, something like "if time < break_time then (some constant plus noise) else (decaying exponential)". A maximum likelihood estimation for that model might require iteration or other operations which are clumsy in Excel -- maybe you should consider VB or Python or some other programming language. I.e. choose the tool to fit the problem and not the other way around.

See Seber and Wild, "Nonlinear Regression", for an extensive discussion of models with discontinuities.

Comment: Hi Robert.  Thanks for the reply.  You are correct about choosing the tool to fit the problem.  Right now Excel is all I have to work on the issue.  :-(

Answer (score 0):

If your data can be generally characterized as having:

(A) a more or less flat plateau region, followed by

(B) a downward trending region

then a basic strategy could be to start at then end of the data and march towards the beginning one point at a time, checking to see that the values are increasing. Once they stop increasing, you've found the break point.

The strategy assumes (unwisely?) that the downward trending region is smooth/noiseless. To make the solution more robust to noise, you could compare values that are 5 apart, or 10 apart, or whatever interval works to filter out the noise. Or you could use a moving average.

This strategy could potentially be made more efficient by starting the search somewhere in the middle of the data but still in downward trending portion. If you know (based on experience) that any value that is (say) 0.5X the maximum is in the downward trending portion, you could start the search there.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

It appears as though you want to detect when the slope changes from something near zero to something negative. One way to detect this is to calculate the 2nd  derivative of the values (calculate the slope of the slope). The 2nd derivative should be near zero in the flat portion of the data *AND* in the downward trending portion of the data. It should go negative at the break point. So finding the minimum (most negative) value of the 2nd should locate the break point.

To implement this, you probably will need to filter noise. So calculate the first derivative (slope) over some suitable window of data:

```
=SLOPE(moving window of say 25 raw values)
```

Then calculate the second derivative (slope of slope):

```
=SLOPE(moving window of say 25 slope values)
```

Then look for the minimum.

Hope that helps.